# Regular Expression - Matching as few occurrences as possible

Tags: javascript, regex

**The Regex:**

```
/(?!\s)([^]+?)\s*((?!.+\)\s*\()\([^-].+ \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} .+\))/g
```

**Input:**

> Some notes(SOME USER (SU950) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)Some other notes(ANOTHER > USER (AU951) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)
>
> Example Notes 
>   Type:OUTBOUND CALL BACK (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:49:10)
>
> some notes on multiple lines
>
> second line of notes (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:52:24)
>
> A new note. (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:55:15)

**Expected Output:**

- Some notes(SOME USER (SU950) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)

  - Some notes
  - (SOME USER (SU950) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)
- Some other notes(ANOTHER > USER (AU951) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)

  - Some other notes
  - (ANOTHER > USER (AU951) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)
- Example Notes Type:OUTBOUND CALL BACK (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:49:10)

  - Example Notes Type:OUTBOUND CALL BACK
  - (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:49:10)
- some notes on multiple lines second line of notes (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:52:24)

  - some notes on multiple lines second line of notes
  - (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:52:24)
- A new note. (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:55:15)

  - A new note.
  - (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:55:15)

***ACTUAL Output:***

- **Some notes(SOME USER (SU950) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)Some other notes(ANOTHER > USER (AU951) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)**

  - **Some notes**
  - **(SOME USER (SU950) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)Some other notes(ANOTHER USER (AU951) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)**
- Example Notes Type:OUTBOUND CALL BACK (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:49:10)

  - Example Notes Type:OUTBOUND CALL BACK
  - (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:49:10)
- some notes on multiple lines second line of notes (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:52:24)

  - some notes on multiple lines second line of notes
  - (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:52:24)
- A new note. (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:55:15)

  - A new note.
  - (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:55:15)

**Regexr:**
http://regexr.com/3d79o

I believe the problem is that i'm not matching as few occurrences as possible when it comes to the last part of the expression however, I've had no success using the +? operator.

Comment: I'd suggest to update post showing clearly what is input and what is expected output.

Comment: is the format fixed or does it changes?

Comment: if it is fixed, then https://regex101.com/r/cS2oH0/1 should work

Comment: works great - a much simpler expression than mine too, add it as an answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it will be using following `regex`, (if the format is fixed)

```
([^(]*)(\(.*?\(?.*?\).*?\))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cS2oH0/1)**

*Javascript Code*

```
var re = /([^(]*)(\(.*?\(?.*?\).*?\))/g; 
var str = 'Some notes(SOME USER (SU950) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)Some other notes(ANOTHER > USER (AU951) 16/09/2015 16:56:38)\n\nExample Notes Type:OUTBOUND CALL BACK (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:49:10)\n\nsome notes on multiple lines\n\nsecond line of notes (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:52:24)\n\nA new note. (USER NAME (UN973) 18/09/2015 11:55:15)';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
      re.lastIndex++;
  }
  print(m[0]);
  print(m[1]);
  print(m[2]);
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/ersacf)**